# Jade code hide/display multichecklist based on checkbox condition

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to display/hide a multichecklist component based on the `checkbox` condition (checked/unchecked).

If the checkbox is checked, multichecklist component show be visible. Else if it is unchecked, multichecklist component should be hidden.

Please find my Jade code below without `checkbox` condition.

```
  .col-lg-12
  input(type='checkbox')
  label(for="show_branch")  Show Branch Dealer

.row.multiselect-controls
  .col-lg-3.col-md-4
    multichecklist(
    list-id="region", 
    list-title="{{'regionTitle'|translate}}",
    list-items="regions", 
    on-select="onRegionSelect", 
    on-deselect="onRegionDeselect", 
    )
```

Please find the screenshot attached.

[image]

**Update 1**

Please find my jade file

```
.col-lg-12
      input(type='checkbox', id='showBranchDealer', ng-click="delegate.onShowBranchDealer();")
      label(for="show_branch_dealer")  Show Branch Dealer


.col-lg-3.col-md-4
multichecklist(
list-id="region", 
list-title="{{'regionTitle'|translate}}",
list-items="regions", 
on-select="onRegionSelect", 
on-deselect="onRegionDeselect", 
)
```

Please find my coffee script file

```
onShowBranchDealer: ->
   if (document.getElementById('showBranchDealer').checked)
     alert("Checked..");
   else
      alert("Unchecked");
```

In this code, my alert message is working fine. But now, i want to hide `list-id="region",` (multichecklist) element instead of alert message.

**Update 2**

```
.col-lg-3.col-md-4
    multichecklist(
    list-id="region", 
    ng-class="isHidden"
    list-title="{{'regionTitle'|translate}}",
    list-items="regions", 
    on-select="onRegionSelect", 
    on-deselect="onRegionDeselect", 
    )
```

I have updated the above code in `.jade` file, but i didnt do any changes in `.coffee` file. Still hide/display functionality is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.col-lg-6.col-md-offset-6
  input(type='checkbox', id='showBranchDealer', ng-click="delegate.onShowBranchDealer();")
  label(for="show_branch_dealer")  Show Branch Dealer
```

I have used `ng-show` attribute in my `jade` file.

```
.col-lg-3.col-md-4
multichecklist(
list-id="region", 
ng-show="showBranchDealers", 
list-title="{{'regionTitle'|translate}}",
list-items="regions", 
on-select="onRegionSelect", 
on-deselect="onRegionDeselect", 
)
```

Please find my changes in `coffee script` file

```
onShowBranchDealer: ->
      if(document.getElementById('showBranchDealer').checked)
        $scope.showBranchDealers = true
      else
        $scope.showBranchDealers = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **[ngClass]** to bind a property, so you can set when it will be display.

```
.col-lg-3.col-md-4
    multichecklist(
    list-id="region", 
    [ngClass]="isHidden"
    list-title="{{'regionTitle'|translate}}",
    list-items="regions", 
    on-select="onRegionSelect", 
    on-deselect="onRegionDeselect", 
    )
```

where `isHidden` is your property to decide when it show or not.

Hope this help.

Comment: How can i set "isHidden" property from `coffeescript` ?

Comment: define a property in your component.ts and call it in the template.

Comment: I have provide my updates in question itself. Its not working still. Am unsure on where to make changes in `.coffee` file.